# Reverse for 'logout' not found. 'logout' is not a valid view function or pattern name (help)

Tags: python, django

i get an Error django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'logout' not found. 'logout' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
even though i got everything in the right plays, i will show you some of the code

Comment: accounts/urls.py
from django.urls import path
from . import views
app_name = "accounts"
urlpatterns = [
      path('signup/', views.signup_view, name='SignUp'),
      path('login/', views.login_view, name='Login'),
      path('logout/', views.logout_view, name='Logout')



]

Comment: base.html (the line i put the logout)
 <form class="logout-link" action="{% url 'accounts:logout' %}" method="post">

Comment: Please post a minimum working program.

Answer (score 0):

The name parameter is case sensitive. Rename it to `logout`.

`path('logout/', views.logout_view, name='logout')`